# Explain BadNeighbors problem statement

Tags: dynamic-programming

I was solving a problem on topcoder http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=2402&rd=5009 .

There is one example :
`{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }`

`Returns: 16`

So my question how its answer is `16` ?

Comment: Please make your question more-self contained. It's okay to link to another website to give some context, but should that website go down your question should stand on its own.

Answer (score 2):

This is $3 + 5 + 3 + 5$. More generally, what the problem wants you to solve is *maximum weight independent set* over a cycle. You can solve this using dynamic programming in linear time.